# Getting RTTI information on a smart pointer

Tags: delphi, smart-pointers, rtti, spring4d

Using Spring, when I declare a smart pointer for a record

```
SmartPerson =  IShared<Pperson>;
```

And then create it

```
Smartperson := Shared<PPerson>.Make;
```

*by the way, think this is really cool.

How then do I go about getting RTTI on the smart pointer? Obviously, I know it's based on a TPerson record, but what steps are needed to sort of reverse what happens when Spring allocates the pointer in the first place?

I see when the record pointer is created it uses code like this

```
 tkPointer: IShared<Pointer>(Result) := Shared.TRecordFinalizer.Create(TypeInfo(T));
```

followed by code like this

```
constructor Shared.TRecordFinalizer.Create(typeInfo: PTypeInfo);
var
  Size : integer;
begin
  inherited Create;
  fTypeInfo := typeInfo.TypeData.RefType^;
  size := GetTypeSize(fTypeInfo);
  fValue := AllocMem(Size);
end;
```

My Question is how do I get, for example, a field of the record the smart pointer points to by using the smart pointer itself?

Hope that makes sense, and maybe another dumb question.

---

To give some more background to problem. I have a factory which uses RTTI to build a control for a field of a record.

```
procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Task := Shared<pTaskRecord>.make;
  Task.AnalysisDates.ES := now;

  Task.TaskType := TTaskTypes.DelayTask;

  ControlFactory := TControlFactory.create(Self);

  Edit := Controlfactory.GetControl('TAnalysisDates','ES');
  if assigned(Edit) then
  begin
    AddObject(Edit.Invoke);
    Edit.Value := @Task.AnalysisDates;
   end;
 end;
```

Which works. It returns an TDateEdit based on attribute tags on a record

I was thinking perhaps what I could do is this

```
Edit := Controlfactory.GetControl(Task,Task.ES);  
//passing in my smart pointer, along with field
```

then the factory would have everything it needs to hook the control up without having to do it in code myself.

```
  Edit.Value := @Task.AnalysisDates;
```

the above line could be handled by the factory. Anyway just an idea

Comment: Not dumb but to me this sounds really like an XY Problem - step back and explain what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: I think I was barking up the wrong tree. I use a lot of RTTI to build maintenance forms on the fly, and I was thinking how can I get RTTI not from attributes on a record, but just tagging a smart pointer to the record instead, then I'd have all the information I would need just by interogating my smart pointer. I could get the pointer to the record, I could have all the fields from the pointer to the record. But I realised this may be pretty stupid.